# Is it possible to detour Built-In JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to see argument passed to a built in JavaScript function alert() using following code. Once I get the argument passed to it, now I want to call the real(built-in) function, so that the code doesn't break.

```
built_in_alert = alert;
function alert(text)// Our custom alert function.
{ 

console.log('Alert function called with param :'+ text);
built_in_alert("Calling with "+text) // try to call the actual built in alert() function.

return 0;

}

alert("hi");
```

This code somehow goes to infinite recursion.

Comment: When you assign something to non primitive type, it is assigned as a reference. In your case, you're assigning `built_in_alert` to a function (non primitive) called `alert`, So essentially, your `built_in_alert` and `alert` are same things. :)

Comment: Function declarations are hoisted. So you are doing `function alert() {}; built_in_alert = alert;`.

Comment: the function declaration is hoisted and occurs before `built_in_alert`.

Comment: @AdityaParab: This doesn't have anything to do with primitives or objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with Amin Jafari that it's generally not a good idea to replace built-in functions, but there can be cases where it's useful for testing or other reasons.

That said, the reason your code doesn't work is that your replacement `alert()` function is in this form:

```
function alert( text ) { ... }
```

Function declarations are processed *before* any other code in the same scope is executed. This is sometimes called "function hoisting", although that is a bit of a misnomer. (The function isn't actually *moved* as the term "hoisting" implies.)

In any case, this replaces the built-in `alert()` function *before* you save it into your `built_in_alert` variable.

Do it like this instead:

```
alert = function( text ) { ... }
```

Because you're now using an ordinary assignment to replace the built-in `alert()`, the replacement happens when and where you expect it.

Try it here:

```js
built_in_alert = alert;
alert = function( text ) { 
    console.log( 'Alert function called with param :'+ text );
    built_in_alert( 'Calling with ' + text );
}

alert( 'hi' );
```

Answer (score 0):

it'd be best if you wouldn't use a reserved name for your function, but if you really want to do it (which I say again is a bad idea) you have to call the actual `alert()` using the `window`: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/3f8zzfdb/)**

```
function alert(text)// Our custom alert function.
{ 

console.log('Alert function called with param :'+ text);
window.alert("Calling with "+text); // try to call the actual built in alert() function.

return 0;

}

alert("hi");
```

Comment: This has the same problem if `function alert() {}` is defined in global scope.

Comment: I know but can I ask, why would anyone ever do that? it's like they're trying to get an error out!

Comment: No idea about the downvotes. But my guess is this example doesn't take into account the possible scopes. It has no mention of what context you're declaring alert function on.
Plus, it has possibility of overriding `window.alert` for all the non primiteves are always by reference.

Comment: @AminJafari - I upvoted your answer. It does what it needs to.

Comment: @AdityaParab that's exactly why I said this is a bad idea to write a function using the built-in function name!

Comment: @AdityaParab: This doesn't have anything to do with primitives or objects.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```
function custom_alert(text)// Our custom alert function.
{ 
    console.log('Alert function called with param :'+ text);
    window.built_in_alert("Calling with "+text);
    return 0;
}

if (!window.built_in_alert) {
    window.built_in_alert = alert;
    window.alert = custom_alert;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Hi are you looking like this ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var text = "hello";
dynamicalert("Custom function "+text )
}
function dynamicalert(_text) {
alert(_text)
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

if you want to use name attribute then

alert(document.getElementsByName("username")[0].value);